# Verilog if else structure

Tags: parsing, verilog, hdl

a very simple question but want to know for parsing purpose :

Are these two structures same in verilog?

*first code* :

```
if_0                                        
else begin
          if_1
          else begin
                    if_2
                    end
          end
end
```

*second code* :

```
if 
    else if
        else if 
        end
    end
end
```

Or is there any instance you can think of where *if else begin if* and *if else if* might be different in any code structure?

Comment: Rather than ask here, you should consult the Verilog standard.

Comment: May I know how you think this might be phrased in 2/3 words?

Comment: Both are wrong. Neither has matching `begin..end` pairs. Get that corrected and we might be able to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of an `if` statement is

```
if (condition) true_statement; else false_statement;
```

Where the `else false_statement;` is optional.
The use of `begin/end` is a distinct topic. Anywhere one procedural statement is allowed, you can replace it with a compound set of statements inside a `begin/end` block, and that includes wrapping one statement with `begin/end`. And `if/else` is considered a single statement. So you can have the following all mean the same thing

```
initial if (cond2) A=1; else if (cond2) B = 2; else C = 3;
initial begin if (cond1) A=1; else if (cond2) B = 2; else C = 3; end
initial if (cond1) A=1; else begin if (cond2) B = 2; else C = 3; end
initial if (cond1) A=1; else if (cond2) B = 2; else begin C = 3; end
initial begin if (cond1) begin A=1; end else begin if (cond2) begin B = 2 end ; else begin C = 3; end end end
```

Note that SystemVerilog adds labeling to `begin : name` and `end : name` to help match them up.

Answer (score 1):

syntax of the `if` statement is

```
if (condition) begin
end
```

Taking the above in account, the following constructs are equivalent

```
if (condition1) begin
   ...
end
else begin
   if (condition2) begin
      ...
   end
   else begin
      ...
   end
end
```

and

```
 if (condition1) begin
     ...
 end
 else if (condition2) begin
     ...
 end
 else begin
     ...
 end
```